# Can I get this binding into a style?

Tags: wpf, resources, styles, resourcedictionary

I would like to take the xaml I currently have for a ComboBox (below), and condense it into something like the Style also shown below. I *think* this should work, but I have a 'Type'ing issue and not sure how to resolve it

```
"Cannot resolve the Style Property 'Margin'. Verify that the owning type is the Style's TargetType, or use Class.Property syntax to specify the Property.)
```

As I look at the existing ComboBoxStyle (also below) that I'm looking to base this new style off of, I see that I hadn't used x:Type, but it does seem to work.

Is there any reason this new style shouldn't work? What must I change?

Cheers,
Berryl

**combo box, as is, working):**

```
<ComboBox 
    x:Name="cboDepartmentFilter" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}"
    Margin="{StaticResource FliterPanelItem_Margin}" Width="{StaticResource FilterPanelItem_Width}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DepartmentFilterControl.Choices}"                     
    ToolTip="{Binding DepartmentFilterControlData.ToolTipTitle}"                    
    />
```

**what I want:**

```
<ComboBox Style="{StaticResource FilterPanelComboBoxStyle}" DataContext="{Binding DepartmentFilterControl}"  />

<!- in some resource file ->
<Style x:Key="FilterPanelComboBoxStyle" BasedOn="{StaticResource ComboBoxStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="{StaticResource FliterPanelItem_Margin}" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="{StaticResource FilterPanelItem_Width}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Choices}" />
    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding ToolTipTitle}" />
</Style>

<!--
```

This style defines a common margin for items in a filter panel.
  -->
    
    150

**existing ComboBoxStyle:**

```
<!-- ComboBox Style -->
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyle" TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource headerBrush}" />
    ...
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
        ...
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxItemStyle}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem" Value="True" />

</Style>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You still need to specify the `TargetType` in the derived style. (Or you prefix the properties with `"ComboBox."`)

Comment: yeah, the obvious! i figured that out and was about to edit this but you beat me to it. Cheers